# FromRow for my data which isn't polymorphic:

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create an instance for my data which isn't polymorphic:

```
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow
data MyData = A | B | C 

instance FromRow MyData where
  fromRow = MyData <$> field -- doesn't compile
```

But it doesn't compile.

UPDATE:

I can't get it to compile

```
instance FromField MyData where
  fromField f mbs = 
    case mbs of
      Just val -> A --????
      Nothing -> returnError ConversionFailed f "error"
```

This throws an error  `Couldn't match expected type ‘Conversion MyData with actual type MyData`

How to make it return `Conversion MyData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to come up with

```
fromRow :: RowParser MyData
```

You have

```
field :: FromField a => RowParser a
```

which makes a `RowParser` (a fragment of a parser for a row) for any `FromField` instance.

You could write

```
fromRow = field
```

to parse single-field rows as `MyData`. However, your `MyData` type doesn't really look like the sort of thing that should have a `FromRow` instance at all. It should probably have (only) a `FromField` instance.

The biggest technical problem with your current code is that you're trying to map a *type constructor* over something. You can only map *functions* (including data constructors and record field accessors).

---

#### Response to update

You might want

```
instance FromField MyData where
  fromField f mbs = do
    char <- fromField f mbs
    case char of
      'A' -> pure A
      'B' -> pure B
      'C' -> pure C
      _ -> returnError ConversionFailed f [char]
```

This should work if you're trying to convert the contents of a field containing a character to your type. If you're dealing with a different sort of field format, you may have to make adjustments.

This is a very common approach to using parser combinator libraries. Instead of building a parser for your type from scratch, you should usually look first to see if the library offers parsers for a similar type, or components of your type. You can then use the standard `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` operations, as well as any special ones the library provides, to build your parser on top.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.1.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html) - here is an example for "reading" a UUID - try to adapt it to your needs

Comment: @OskarK, I've updated my answer, but I suspect you need to learn some more Haskell basics before playing with this sort of library.

Comment: and if I had a string constructor, not a char?

Comment: @OskarK, you'd just need to change `char` to `str` (for clarity), `'A'` to `"A"`, etc, and change the error call to use `str` instead of `[char]`. My understanding is that this all depends on the database field configuration, but I know very little about databases.

Comment: @OskarK, would you mind telling me what errors? I may have made some silly mistake.